# How to read values from an Excel document using Angular

Tags: angular

I want to read an excel file and return the data in the this.listEmployeeImport array. When it calls the onImportExcel method it returns []

```
 async onImportExcel(event:any){
    /* wire up file reader */
    this.file= event.target.files[0];
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
          fileReader.onload = (e) => {
              this.arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;
              var data = new Uint8Array(this.arrayBuffer);
              var arr = new Array();
              for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
              var bstr = arr.join("");
              var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:"binary"});
              var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
              var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
              this.listEmployeeImport = (XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{
                raw: false,
                dateNF: "dd/mm/yyyy"
              }));
  
           
  
          }
          await fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file);
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1 - Using an Observable**

One possibility would be to return the output wrapped in an observable. For example you could do something like this:

```
    onImportExcel(event: any): Observable<any> {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        this.file = event.target.files[0];

        return new Observable((observer: any) => {

            reader.onload = (e) => {

                // Code omitted for brevity 
                
                const result = (XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{
                        raw: false,
                        dateNF: "dd/mm/yyyy"
                }));

                observer.next(result);
                observer.complete();
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file);
        });
    }
```

Then you can call the method like this:

```
this.onImportExcel(ev).subscribe(res => console.log('Parsed Excel-Doc:', res));
```

---

**Solution 2 - Using a Promise**

There is actually an alternative solution where a Promise is returned instead of an observable.
Similar to solution 1, this solution is an asynchronous solution since the return-value has to be awaited.

```
    async importExcelDoc(event: any) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        const result = await this.parseExcelDoc(file).catch(err => console.error(err));
        console.log('Parsed Excel-Doc:', result);
    }

    parseExcelDoc(file: File): Promise<any> {
        /* wire up file reader */               
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fileReader.onload = (e) => {

                // Code omitted for brevity 

                const result = (XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{
                    raw: false,
                    dateNF: "dd/mm/yyyy"
                }));
                resolve(result);          
            }
            fileReader.onerror = reject;
            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        });
    };
```

Comment: I want to read a file asynchronously

Comment: I now added (and tested!) a second solution using a Promise instead of an Observable. Both of my solutions are actually asynchronous since you need to wait for the return-value.

It doesn't really make sense to await `readAsArrayBuffer()` since after this method has been completed, the Excel-document has not yet been fully processed. Therefore it's useless to return a value at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [read-excel-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file) package, which also allows you to specify the Schema model for how your data will be parsed:

```
import readXlsxFile from 'read-excel-file';

...

// We will map column with name "A" to property "property_1", and column
// with name "B" to property "property_2" for each item.
const schema = {
  'A': { prop: 'property_1', type: String },
  'B': { prop: 'propert_2', type: String },
};

async importExcelDoc(event: any) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  const data = await readXlsxFile(file, { schema });
};
```